# Check if the database has been created on Android

Tags: android, database

How can I know if the database has been created or not in Android?  Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 3):

[image]you will find the data in

DDMS -> data/data/your_package_name/databases/yourdatabase_name

[image]

see the second image
you can also check database through command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Use SQLiteOpenHelper. It will take care of creating, if not yet created. And even updates can be done easily with SQLiteOpenHelper.

Example Code can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NotePadProvider.html