# How to interact with sqlite3 in command line on Android application?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I see Android terminal has a function, we can use sqlite3 and interact with it and modify my database.

I try to use `Runtime().getRuntime().exec("sqlite3 mydb.db")` to open mydb.db, but only what I can do is to insert and delete some data. That is not what I want to do. I want to select some information from mydb.db and I can get those information and show it in my EditText.

Answer (score 2):

Android ships the `sqlite3` executable for debugging purposes.

From the code, you should use the java primitives, as describes [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)

You can check examples from the sdk, I think "Contact Manager" is showing it off.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a adb shell in windows

```
 C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb shell sqlite3
    SQLite version 3.7.4
    Enter ".help" for instructions
    Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
    sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
To intercat with sqlite through  command prompt 

use following commands


C:\> adb shell 

then

# sqlite3 /data/data/your_package_name/databases/databasename 

to see which table are created under it 

sqlite > .tables

and .help for instructions 

use can see this answer also
```

[Check if the database has been created on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601917/check-if-the-database-has-been-created-on-android/6530550#6530550)

**Links for tutorials**

http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/1/

http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/**

Comment: Thank you. But I want to interact with sqlite3 in may application not in adb shell command line. We can do those works easily, but how to do it in application is a hard work for me. I want to accomplisth the purpose in my application.

Comment: i gave the answer on basis of your question How to interact with sqlite3 in command line on Android application ? i have added two new link , are really good tutorials for database application check them

Answer (score 1):

- you can do a `SELECT` on sqlite on the command line but then the output will be (by default) directed to the standard output stream. so you can't catch it directly inside your program.
- you can configure sqlite3 to output to a file by using the command `.output FILENAME` inside the sqlite3 prompt. then read the output file in your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first method do not work. I will try the second method soon.

Comment: Thank you! I see. I found a solution, that is when I write out and flush SELECT command into sqlite3, I must close this out stream, then I am able to get the output result. But this solution has a shortcoming, if I want to write out another sql command into sqlite3, I will get nothing. So I have to interact with sqlite3 from the beginning. To some degree it looks like After I speak with sqlite3 just one sentence, I have to say goodbye to it, and if I want to say two sentences, I have to speak two times.....

Comment: i usually don't ask such questions .. the asker usually knows his problem best .. but .. do you really need to interact with sqlite3 using `Runtime`? .. if you just want a way to access and manipulate your database, then you can use the android java sdk. it provides a really good and straight forward usage. check this for a starting point [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)